# Restrict access until user has confirmed email link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am playing around the Identity.Samples example and found out that a user can still login without clicking on the email confirmation after registering. Is there a flag to turn on to restrict the user from logging in until he/she clicks the confirm link in his/her email? Or any extra code that I need to write to prevent this?

EDIT: Added the Login action code from the samples

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doen't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the Login action look like with the sample?  Maybe you need to add additional logic to check that the "confirmation flag" against the account is set?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the sample?  I was having a look at http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity, and the only thing that is prevented for an unconfirmed account is change of password.

Comment: First of all you need to set a flag inside the Database, so that whenever any user Register's for the first time, set the flag to 'False', and change this flag to 'True' whenever a user clicks the confirmation URL. Now whenever the user tries to login check for the Flag whether its 'True' or not. If its 'True' the user has clicked the confirmation link else not.

Comment: these are not the answer !! why there is an useless SignInStatus.RequiresVerification!!!

Answer (score 12):

If you want to require emailConfirmation, just add an additional check like this before you try the passwordSignIn:

```
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
               if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)) return View("ErrorNotConfirmed");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Hao for confirming that "PasswordSignInAsync" won't do 2FA on its own. From the 2.1.0-alpha Samples it really looks like it should do this check for you. I'm curious how does one hit the  "RequiresVerification" scenario when calling "PasswordSignInAsync" in 2.2.0-alpha (or is this even possible)?

Comment: I think after a couple of days I'm starting to realize why this has been implemented like this. Please confirm if my thinking is correct... My below "fix" combines the aspects of email confirmation & two-factor authentication into one, which probably isn't right for those that want _real_ 2FA (log-in, get code on phone\email, enter code, then get authorized to enter site). Is this the same functionality that the Identity framework is providing? If so, then my answer below is not right for 2FA.

Comment: Yeah, your SignInAsync smushes those together

Comment: This would allow an attacker to find out who has not yet confirmed their email. Better to return the same action as per invalid password.

Answer (score 8):

Like JT I think you should check to make sure they are authenticated before letting them know they have to confirm the email address.  Otherwise anyone could use your system to see if that email exists in your system.  So I put Hao's code after signin.success

```
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
                        {                                                        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                            ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
                            return View("DisplayEmail");
                        }
                    }
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed, I was fussing around trying to make a filter for this and I had in my mind I would apply it to each account method, I'm not sure why I didn't think to just not allow them to log in at all...very stupid of me, thanks again. This was perfect.

Answer (score 6):

Based off of Hao's response I decided to write my own "SignInManager.SignInAsync" method to handle email confirmation before login. Not sure if this will help anyone else (or if there's a better way of doing this), but thought I'd share. One thing to note is that the functionality is a little different from Hao's suggestion. In order to get the "RequiresValidation" returned the user would have to first provide a valid username and password.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) 
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public async Task<SignInStatus> SignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        if (user == null) return SignInStatus.Failure;

        if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id)) return SignInStatus.LockedOut;

        if (!await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
        {
            await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
            if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            {
                return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
            }

            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        }

        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
        {
            return SignInStatus.RequiresVerification;
        }

        await base.SignInAsync(user, rememberMe, false);
        return SignInStatus.Success;
    }
}
```

**Update 1**: After some thought, I don't think this is right for 2FA. Based off of other site's 2FA implementation (Mandrill for one) they have users enter their user\pass, then additionally enter a passcode sent to their phone before they are authorized to enter the site. This is different from just verifying the email account before the user\pass is allowed to be used. I do like my implementation for Email Confirmation better since it doesn't divulge users accounts, but *its not 2FA*.

**Update 2**: Removed the check for GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(). The above code is for preventing sign in until email confirmation is received and doesn't have anything to do with 2FA (you actually can't do 2FA with the above method since a token is never sent or validated before the user is signed in).

Comment: PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true) contains that `shouldLockout` parameter... Doesn't look to me like your implementation handles that...Or am I wrong? I'm going to give your implementation a try, but I'm curious what you think about the lockout thing..

Comment: SignInStatus.RequiresVerification is related to 2FA and not the original question. Hau's response is still required in addition to the code you've written. It doesn't look like SignInStatus has a value for  "Email not confirmed". For anyone who is curious, here's the code I used (Note that I'm also using T4MVC) https://gist.github.com/alexdresko/ce6e8ac478fca31d36c0

Comment: @AlexDresk - There was an issue in the code related to the !(IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id) && IsPhoneConfirmed). It should be || (I've updated the sample above as well).

Comment: @AlexDresko - You are correct. I was mixing up email confirmation and 2FA. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: So your method now handles the email validation that Hao recommends, but doesn't do the 2FA stuff? Just want to clarify... If so, I'll update my code to use this tonight. I don't need 2FA yet, but it would be good to get that working as well.

Comment: @AlexDresko - Correct, it actually never did 2FA. I was mixing up the terminology of email validation & 2FA. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Also, to clarify, my code is very similar to Hao suggestion of checking `IsEmailConfirmed(...)` before calling `PasswordSignIn(...)` except that I verify the username\password before displaying the error in order to prevent people from searching for unauthenticated usernames. It'd probably be just as easy to check after calling PasswordSignIn and immediately logging out if their email is not confirmed.